# Issues implementing AdMob with Firebase iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, admob

So ever since the announcement came that iAD would be shutting down I started searching for an alternative way to monetize my app using advertisements. And with Google's May 18th updates to Firebase (integrating AdMob with it was very appealing), I decided to add a simple banner ad to my app. I followed all the instructions in the documentation (https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/ios/quick-start#load_an_ad_into_gadbannerview) however I am unfortunately getting some critical errors.

Here is the code from the documentation, it nearly identical to my application code:

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMobileAds

class ViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var bannerView: GADBannerView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

  bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716"
  bannerView.rootViewController = self
  bannerView.loadRequest(GADRequest())
}

}
```

At `@IBOutlet weak var bannerView: GADBannerView!` I am getting the error: `weak may only be applied to class and class-bound protocol types, not '<<error type>>` Which is an error that I have never seen in my life!

I am also getting `Use of unresolved identifier 'GADRequest`, which I do not understand because that is a built in method from GADBannerView...?

I installed all the necessary libraries using cocoapods so that shouldn't be a problem. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is you cocoapods the newest version?

I had a similar issue with old version of cocoapods after adding firebase to my project which has GoogleMobileAds implemented already.

I got 3 build errors after I import Firebase:

"Use of unresolved identifier GADRequest"

"Use of unresolved identifier GADBannerViewDelegate"

"Use of unresolved identifier GADBannerView"

I commented `import Firebase` and those errors gone.

I decided to update my cocoapods and delete my old podfile.

Then use `pod init` to create a new podfile and add dependencies.
Of course install pods again.

This works for me.

Not sure it works in your case or not, but I hope it helps.

Answer (score 10):

```
import Firebase
```

in ViewController

Comment: Import FireBase instead of GoogleMobileAds worked for me.
The google quick start is wrong and lead me to this issue too https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/ios/quick-start p

Answer (score 7):

The solution is very simple, just import both Firebase & GoogleMobileAds :

```
import Firebase
import GoogleMobileAds
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to import `Firebase`.

I solved all problems as unpredictable error, compile error and import error using this way.
I am using Xcode8.x with Swift3.

1. Uninstall cocoapod if you installed in your iOS project. (Delete all pod folders, pod frameworks and workspace made by pod). Does not matter `Podfile`.
2. Edit `Podfile` as below

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'YourTargetName' do
    use_frameworks!
    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod 'Firebase/AdMob'
end
```

3. In terminal, type `pod update`
4. `pod install`
5. Open project through `yourproject.workspace` made by `cocoapod`

import `GoogleMobileAds` and do anything you want.

Booooooom!

I hope it help you guys. 
And you can download examples by google [here](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-ios-examples/releases/tag/6.5).

Answer (score 1):

I solved it updating cocoapods to the latest version, installing all pods again and clean the project

Answer (score 0):

I may be late to the Party but along side GoogleMobileAds. We have to import Firebase. Dont know the reason but that solve my problem. I have ran into same kind of problem on different occasions.

Answer (score 0):

When you use Pod to install,
Don't forget to unmark **'use_framework!'**

I reinstall pods again with 'use_framework' , it's work! 
And you don't need to **import Firebase** when you try to use GADBannerview.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase/Google Ads, Swift, Xcode, and Cocoapods are constantly updating. I have been changing how to declare the pods and importing them over the years.

Now (year 2018), your Podfile should be written like this:

```
pod 'Firebase/AdMob'
```

That's all. It's consolidated under the subspec "AdMob", under the one big family of Firebase. You run a `pod install` and you will realize there is a dependency to the pod "Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK" (but you should not add the pod to the Podfile).

You need to `import Firebase`, and the project should resolve `GADRequest` etc.

It will work, until one of them change the way to integrate, again.