# GADMobileAds.configure(withApplicationID: "AppID here") not working

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, admob

I am trying to implement a banner ad in my app and have run into a roadblock.

**This is my code:**

```
import UIKit
import Firebase




@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    FIRApp.configure()
    GADMobileAds.configure(withApplicationID: "APPID HERE")
    return true
}
```

**This is my error:**

`Use of unresolved identifier GADMobileAds`

I have been watching a few videos now and can't seem to find out where I have gone wrong, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO Trlewi. You need to put some more effort into your questions to receive some help. What is "Not Working" ? What errors do you run into ? What is the desired behaviour?
 https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you sneak forgot to put the error message in

Comment: Look if this helps you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37834509/issues-implementing-admob-with-firebase-ios  I am not familiar with Swift or Admob but you probably forgot something like **import GoogleMobileAds**

Comment: thank you yes that helped a lot!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Issues implementing AdMob with Firebase iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37834509/issues-implementing-admob-with-firebase-ios)